# RTL constructed script can't be typeset properly in LuaLaTeX?

Tags: luatex, kerning, bidi

I have a grammar for one of my constructed languages, which uses its own right-to-left script. In my font for this script, I have the glyphs mapped to the Private Use Area and rely on wrapping text in this script with an RLO and a PDF, so *cenvos* would be represented as `RLO E000 E001 E002 E004 E005 E006 PDF`. The following example typesets correctly in XeLaTeX (for now, ignore that `#` and `+` are switched):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Npn \cen_convert_one:N #1 {
    \str_case:nn { #1 } {
        % use PUA space because regular space makes XeLaTeX lays out words LTR
        { \__cen_space: } { \symbol{"E023} }
        { c } { \symbol{"E000} }
        { e } { \symbol{"E001} }
        { n } { \symbol{"E002} }
        { ŋ } { \symbol{"E003} }
        { v } { \symbol{"E004} }
        { o } { \symbol{"E005} }
        { s } { \symbol{"E006} }
        { þ } { \symbol{"E007} }
        { š } { \symbol{"E008} }
        { r } { \symbol{"E009} }
        { l } { \symbol{"E00A} }
        { ł } { \symbol{"E00B} }
        { m } { \symbol{"E00C} }
        { a } { \symbol{"E00D} }
        { f } { \symbol{"E00E} }
        { g } { \symbol{"E00F} }
        { p } { \symbol{"E010} }
        { t } { \symbol{"E011} }
        { č } { \symbol{"E012} }
        { î } { \symbol{"E013} }
        { j } { \symbol{"E014} }
        { i } { \symbol{"E015} }
        { d } { \symbol{"E016} }
        { ð } { \symbol{"E017} }
        { h } { \symbol{"E018} }
        { ħ } { \symbol{"E019} }
        { ê } { \symbol{"E01A} }
        { ô } { \symbol{"E01B} }
        { â } { \symbol{"E01C} }
        { u } { \symbol{"E01D} }
        { . } { \symbol{"E01E} }
        { ; } { \symbol{"E01F} }
        { ? } { \symbol{"E020} }
        { ! } { \symbol{"E021} }
        { k } { \symbol{"E022} }
        { + } { \symbol{"E024} }
        { \# } { \symbol{"E025} }
        { \__cen_surname_foreign: } { \symbol{"E026} }
        { \@ } { \symbol{"E027} }
        { * } { \symbol{"E028} }
        { ' } { \symbol{"E029} }
        { 0 } { \symbol{"E030} }
        { 1 } { \symbol{"E031} }
        { 2 } { \symbol{"E032} }
        { 3 } { \symbol{"E033} }
        { 4 } { \symbol{"E034} }
        { 5 } { \symbol{"E035} }
        { 6 } { \symbol{"E036} }
        { 7 } { \symbol{"E037} }
        { 8 } { \symbol{"E038} }
        { 9 } { \symbol{"E039} }
        { A } { \symbol{"E03A} }
        { B } { \symbol{"E03B} }
        { C } { \symbol{"E03C} }
        { D } { \symbol{"E03D} }
        { E } { \symbol{"E03E} }
        { F } { \symbol{"E03F} }
        { \\ } { \\ \symbol{"202E} }
    }
}

\tl_new:N \l__input_t
\str_new:N \l__input

\cs_new_protected:Npn \cen_convert:n #1 {
    % Nasty hack to get around outdated versions of expl3 that don't have
    % str_map_* functions
    \tl_set:Nn \l__input_t { #1 }
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__input_t {~}{\__cen_space:}
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__input_t {+*}{\__cen_surname_foreign:}
    \str_set_eq:NN \l__input \l__input_t
    \symbol{"202E}
    \tl_map_function:NN { \l__input } \cen_convert_one:N
    \symbol{"202C}
}

\cs_new_eq:NN \cenconvert \cen_convert:n

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\rlo}{\symbol{"202E}}
\newcommand{\poprtl}{\symbol{"202C}}
\newcommand{\cenc}{\symbol{"E000}}
\newcommand{\cene}{\symbol{"E001}}

\newfontfamily{\vlina}{vlina.otf}
\newcommand{\textvlina}[1]{{\vlina\cenconvert{#1}}}

\title{test}
\author{\textvlina{\#flirora}}
\date{January 2019}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{flushright}

\textvlina{vanden olonþa genin gašjodos rela; \\
garcen moðona nasenen djorłas searne.}

\textvlina{nava'þ cenčon'ak 16CB}

\textvlina{0123456789ABCDEF}

\textvlina{ca e na ŋa va o sa;}

\textvlina{þa ša ra la ła.}

\textvlina{ma a fa ga pa ta ča;}

\textvlina{în ja i da ða.}

\textvlina{ar ħo ên ôn ân uħo;}

\textvlina{carþ taŋ neŋ es nem.}

\textvlina{elo cenvos.}

\end{flushright}

\end{document}
```

(vlina.otf is [here](https://gitlab.com/Kyarei/uruwi-clongos/raw/master/fonts/vlina.otf?inline=false))

[image: Correct typesetting with XeLaTeX: glyphs are displayed right to left, and kerning is performed correctly.]

However, under LuaLaTeX (version 1.10), the output has the glyphs from left to right:

[image: Incorrect typesetting with LuaLaTeX: glyphs are displayed left to right. Kerning is not broken.]

I tried using `\textdir TRT`, which fixes the direction, but yields broken kerning:

[image: Incorrect typesetting with LuaLaTeX: glyphs are displayed right to left, but kerning is broken.]

Other approaches to fixing the text direction, such as `luabidi`, give similar results.

I think the problem boils down to one of the following:

- LuaTeX is buggy with RLOs, kerning or both
- My font's kerning tables are buggy, even if they give the correct results in other renderers
- I'm one of the few people who want to do this, so this use case isn't supported at all

Comment: what happens if you use `\newfontfamily{\vlina}{vlina.otf}[Renderer=Harfbuzz]` and compile with `lualatex-dev`? (requires a really current texlive or miktex!).

Comment: If I compile with `lualatex-dev` and insert the `\textdir TRT`, then I get the intended result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replacing

```
\newfontfamily{\vlina}{vlina.otf}
\newcommand{\textvlina}[1]{{\vlina\cenconvert{#1}}}
```

with

```
\newfontfamily{\vlina}[Renderer=Harfbuzz]{vlina.otf}
\newcommand{\textvlina}[1]{{\textdir TRT\vlina\cenconvert{#1}}}
```

and compiling with the latest `lualatex-dev` gives the intended result.